# Select-Form with Value integer

Tags: php, html, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm trying to edit users via form.
So far, so good.

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('admin_level', 'Admin?') }}
    {{ Form::select('admin_level', array(0 => 'no', 1 => 'yes'), null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
</div>
```

My problem is: In the rendered version of this form, the value changes to string, but I need an integer value to update the user.
Tried to delete the '' but without any changes. (as you might see above)
DD is giving me this:

```
"admin_level" => "0"
```

How to get the value in 'admin_level' to an integer value?

**UPDATE**

I just added this to my UserController function update:

```
$request['admin_level'] = (int)$request['admin_level'];
```

If I dd($request) in the attributes it's now an integer, but I don't get it stored with:

```
 $user->update($request->except(['_token']));
```

The value keeps the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!

You have to add the attribute to the /app/User.php in array $fillable:

```
    protected $fillable = [
      'name', 'email', 'password', 'admin_level',
    ];
```